# Boost Threaded sockets

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

Just wondered if someone could point me some simple code which shows multi threaded boost::tcp::socket that is multi threaded that does not work off the same socket that is created by the parent I.E.

```
while (TRUE){
    create server
    create shared_ptr io_service
    create shared_ptr socket
    create acceptor 
    create endpoint

    bind to ip and port
    listen
    accept(bind etc)
    create thread pool with function passing the ONE socket

    //do work in thread close the socket
}
```

Comment: Boost Asio is multithreaded. You just have to run `io_service::run()` in more than one thread.

Comment: Have a look at the boost::asio examples http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Comment: I have looked at them and they all use the same socket. I want it to use multiple sockets in multiple threads do you know a specific example where boost uses more than one socket ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of my problem it was the fact that I did not realise that the more than one socket could bind to the same port using boost

```
acceptor->set_option( boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address( true ) );
```

which has helped me a lot.